# Error when redering (cycles, lighting, UV problem)

Tags: rendering, uv, lighting

everyone. This is the render that I made with **my computer**:

[image]

And this is the result when I use **Render Online Farm (like SheepIT)**
[image]

This seems to be where I Unwarp (UV), but where is the error? This is my blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nr4mA6KJILOuo3srxuKpGT98NOnUsSGu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't access the file (error This site can’t be reached), but i am surprised you share a +246MB file. I don't see anything in that render that should be even remotely that heavy.

Comment: Oh, I checked some image texture 4k in 4k video, so it's very heavy. So you can't access it. But I use another account and can go to Google Drive just fine

Comment: Can I provide pictures? what parts do you want to check ? Shader Editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the answer of **Gordon Brinkmann**. I recognize what the problem is. This is the error of new **Color Management** that I try to make the model look more natural: **AgX**

[image]

When I am using this Color Management, all of the black/white images will transform to **Generic Data** (there is no Non-color option in there). And even though I can render it well, for some reason, online platforms like Sketchfab or SheepIt can't interpret this setting, and it makes the lighting wrong

[image]

Changing back to Standard Color Management will fix the issue

Comment: Sketchfab has no notions of different color managements. AGX is available only on custom builds or on version 4.0 which yet to get out of beta release. Renderfarms rarely ever use anything other than stable releases, including sheepit. This is a good illustration of why it is good practice to always mention the release used, especially when you do not use the latest stable.

Answer (score 1):

In the file you provided for download, on the material "Body" the *Image Texture* node containing the normal map "Body_Normal.png" is set to *Color Space* > *sRGB*. If you change this to *Non-Color* everything looks fine.

By the way, all textures you have there (*Metallic*, *Roughness*, *Normal*, *Alpha*, *Displacement*) are better used with the *Non-Color* setting (except for those that really contain the color of the material, like *Base Color* in your shader). In some cases, the *sRGB* results might look better, but usually not.

And I only checked this material where you had an issue with, you might have the same but not noticeable in other materials as well.

[image: normal color space]